# New keyboard shortcut to display Shortcut Overlay (instead of Super)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to set a different shortcut to show *Shortcut Overlay* (the default is <kbd>Super</kbd> alone). I cannot find any relevant setting to modify. How can I define a new keyboard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably already figured this out but you can set a custom shortcut in the settings menu. For the command to run: `/usr/bin/io.elementary.shortcut-overlay`.

I found the command using `lxtask` and opening and closing the shortcut menu repeatedly till I found the process, then did `whereis io.elementary.shortcut-overlay` and finding the location in the output.